# How can I define a proportion table?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I want to make a bar plot showing the state ratio of the American by region. I define the x-axis, but I cannot define the region ratios. How can I do it?

```
library(dslabs)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
data(murders)
ggplot(murders, aes(x = region, y =???))
```

I want an image like this when it's done
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also calculate it within ggplot with `stat_count()` and `y = after_stat(prop)`.

```r
library(dslabs)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
data(murders)

ggplot(murders, aes(region)) +
  stat_count(aes(y = after_stat(prop), group = 1, 
                 fill = after_stat(as.factor(x)))) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Northeast", "North Central", "West", "South")) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = 'Proportion') +
  scale_fill_discrete(guide = "none") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can `count`, calculate  `Proportion` and then plot :

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

murders %>%
  count(region, name = 'Proportion') %>%
  arrange(Proportion) %>%
  mutate(Proportion = Proportion/sum(Proportion), 
        region = factor(region, levels = unique(region))) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(region, Proportion, fill = region) + geom_col()
```

[image]

Comment: Why does anything exist before I wrote geom_col(), is there any way to do it before  geom_col() ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. What do you mean?

Comment: I mean that even though you didn't write geom_bar(), it created bars . How did it happened ? I didnt get it.

Comment: `geom_col` also creates bars. See `?geom_col`

Answer (score 0):

A solution that uses `..count..`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(murders, aes(x = region, fill = region)) +  
  geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Northeast", "North Central", "West", "South"))
```

[image]